# Illegal callback invocation from native module while using react-native-ping library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ping

I am receiving the following error:

"Illegal callback invocation from native module. this callback type only permits a single invocation from native code"

I am creating an app that requires me to use Ping through all of the subnets and it "works" but I continue to receive the error when it is called.

I have been looking through a lot of the various questions on this topics and looking through the answers but I do not understand exactly how to solve this. Some answers have been to use the RCTEventEmitter but I still am unaware as to what to do.

I am utilizing the Ping.start function from the react-native-ping library to accomplish the task of determining what devices are on the network. All of the code works and my understanding of what is going on is that I cannot do multiple Ping.start at the same time. It runs through all 255 subnets to determine if the IP receives a ping and then checks whether or not it is a device that I am looking for or not.

My code is as follows:

```
async function checkIPAddressValid(fourthOctet) {  //scanning the entire subnet on the fourth octect see if every ip address is alive
    let ipSplit;
    ipSplit = gatewayIPAddress.split('.');
    const ipaddress = ipSplit[0] + '.' + ipSplit[1] + '.' + ipSplit[2] + '.' + fourthOctet;

    await Ping.start(ipaddress, {timeout: 1000}).then((response) => {
        if (ipaddress !== gatewayIPAddress && ipaddress !== deviceIPAddress) {
            if (!ipList.includes(ipaddress)) {
                ipList.push(ipaddress);
                const defineResult = DoDefineAsync(ipaddress);
            }
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        //console.log(ipaddress + error + "\n");
    });
}
```

The network ID is determined based on the gatewayIPAddress that I get utilizing the NetworkInfo from the react-native-network-info library.

The Host ID is usually 1-255 so using Ping.start is pings all 255 IP addresses relatively quickly and throws the error.